# Can I install software in OpenSUSE using .deb files? If possible, how?

Tags: opensuse, rpm, deb

I just installed OpenSUSE and set everything up. But I am wondering if OpenSUSE use .deb files to install. If it's possible, how can I do? Can I just use `alien`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.rpm` files or load from community repositories.  499 out of 500 times, the package will be available from a repository registered at the [OpenBuildService](https://software.opensuse.org/search)

For that 1 out of 500 occurrence, where in addition there is no `.rpm`, `alien` allows conversion of `.deb` packages to `.rpm`.  See description [here](https://www.linuxhelp.com/convert-deb-rpm-rpm-deb-package-alien/).

Comment: The website you gave me is unavailable. It's 'error 404 not found'.

Comment: The website is part of the Suse infrastructure, and it is online now.